# How to arrange <ul> properly css?

Tags: css

[image]

this is the `<ul>` I want to arrange this in two-row on mobile with CSS. I am using WordPress so I only have a custom CSS option.

help would be appreciated thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: `display: grid` might be your solution.

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: Yes, I know but This code is just for example..this problem has nothing to do with that code. btw thanks I will take care of that next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
      ul {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
        list-style: none;
        justify-content: space-around;
      }
      ul li {
        padding: 1rem;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <ul>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
      <li>this is text</li>
    </ul>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul{
  display:flex;
flex-wrap:wrap;
  justify-content:center;
  align-items:center;
  list-style:none;
}
ul > li{
  padding:0 5px;
width:20%;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
  <li>this is text</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: can I do something that other `<li>` just go to the second row? So I can get the first 4 on the first row and the second 4 on the second row